Integrating a go function that uses the go livekit sdk with python
I have a function in a go program that uses the livekit sdk for go to make a room for livestreaming and i want to call that function from a python file. I've done some debugging and i can confirm that all this error comes from the line that actually makes the request to create the room but i keep getting this error.
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 140206808236032-byte block (3801088 in use)
fatal error: out of memory

goroutine 17 gp=0xc000006700 m=1 mp=0xc000080008 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw({0x1051fcec5?, 0x105420928?})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1023 +0x5c fp=0xc0000df838 sp=0xc0000df808 pc=0x104e1299c
runtime.(*mcache).allocLarge(0xc00033e580?, 0x7f8470c2d7d8, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:236 +0x18b fp=0xc0000df888 sp=0xc0000df838 pc=0x104df262b
runtime.mallocgc(0x7f8470c2d7d8, 0x105308820, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1165 +0x597 fp=0xc0000df910 sp=0xc0000df888 pc=0x104de9af7
runtime.makeslice(0x10541e518?, 0xc0000bdd60?, 0x0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:107 +0x49 fp=0xc0000df938 sp=0xc0000df910 pc=0x104e2b6c9
google.golang.org/protobuf/proto.MarshalOptions.marshal({{}, 0x10?, 0x0?, 0x0?}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x10541e518, 0xc0000bdd60})
        /Users/pomegranaT/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.34.2/proto/encode.go:189 +0x396 fp=0xc0000dfa08 sp=0xc0000df938 pc=0x104fc26f6
google.golang.org/protobuf/proto.Marshal({0x1054137a8, 0xc0000bdd60})
        /Users/pomegranaT/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.34.2/proto/encode.go:110 +0x50 fp=0xc0000dfa58 sp=0xc0000dfa08 pc=0x104fc2070
github.com/livekit/protocol/livekit.doProtobufRequest({0x105419148, 0xc0002fa960}, {0x105413588, 0xc0002fa360}, 0x0, {0xc0000b0960, 0x51}, {0x1054137a8?, 0xc0000bdd60?}, {0x105413128, ...})
        /Users/pomegranaT/go/pkg/mod/github.com/livekit/protocol@v1.20.1/livekit/livekit_agent_dispatch.twirp.go:1483 +0x91 fp=0xc0000dfb98 sp=0xc0000dfa58 pc=0x10519ef71
github.com/livekit/protocol/livekit.(*roomServiceProtobufClient).callCreateRoom(0xc00031c300, {0x105419148, 0xc0002fa960}, 0xc0000bdd60)
        /Users/pomegranaT/go/pkg/mod/github.com/livekit/protocol@v1.20.1/livekit/livekit_room.twirp.go:155 +0x9f fp=0xc0000dfc28 sp=0xc0000dfb98 pc=0x1051b513f
github.com/livekit/protocol/livekit.(*roomServiceProtobufClient).callCreateRoom-fm({0x105419148?, 0xc0002fa960?}, 0x1053096e0?)
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x36 fp=0xc0000dfc58 sp=0xc0000dfc28 pc=0x1051cd8d6
github.com/livekit/protocol/livekit.(*roomServiceProtobufClient).CreateRoom(0xc00031c300, {0x105419148, 0xc0002fa8d0}, 0xc0000bdd60)
        /Users/pomegranaT/go/pkg/mod/github.com/livekit/protocol@v1.20.1/livekit/livekit_room.twirp.go:150 +0x157 fp=0xc0000dfcd8 sp=0xc0000dfc58 pc=0x1051b4db7
github.com/livekit/server-sdk-go/v2.(*RoomServiceClient).CreateRoom(0xc0002fa390, {0x105419110, 0x1057d6020}, 0xc0000bdd60)
        /Users/pomegranaT/go/pkg/mod/github.com/livekit/server-sdk-go/v2@v2.2.1/roomclient.go:49 +0xf3 fp=0xc0000dfdb0 sp=0xc0000dfcd8 pc=0x1051f7193
main.CreateRoom({0x104a7f920, 0x7f8470c2d7d0})
        /Users/pomegranaT/Projects/livekit-go/main.go:33 +0xae fp=0xc0000dfe28 sp=0xc0000dfdb0 pc=0x1051f7b2e
_cgoexp_385523192a9c_CreateRoom(0x7ffeebaf73d8)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:58 +0x25 fp=0xc0000dfe58 sp=0xc0000dfe28 pc=0x1051f81e5
runtime.cgocallbackg1(0x1051f81c0, 0x7ffeebaf73d8, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:403 +0x295 fp=0xc0000dff18 sp=0xc0000dfe58 pc=0x104de0b95
runtime.cgocallbackg(0x1051f81c0, 0x7ffeebaf73d8, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:322 +0x136 fp=0xc0000dff90 sp=0xc0000dff18 pc=0x104de0856
runtime.cgocallbackg(0x1051f81c0, 0x7ffeebaf73d8, 0x0)
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x29 fp=0xc0000dffb8 sp=0xc0000dff90 pc=0x104e4a0a9
runtime.cgocallback(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1079 +0xcc fp=0xc0000dffe0 sp=0xc0000dffb8 pc=0x104e479ec
runtime.goexit({})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc0000dffe8 sp=0xc0000dffe0 pc=0x104e47c21

goroutine 2 gp=0xc000006c40 m=nil [force gc (idle)]:
runtime.gopark(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc00007afa8 sp=0xc00007af88 pc=0x104e158ce
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:408
runtime.forcegchelper()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:326 +0xb3 fp=0xc00007afe0 sp=0xc00007afa8 pc=0x104e15753
runtime.goexit({})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc00007afe8 sp=0xc00007afe0 pc=0x104e47c21
created by runtime.init.6 in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:314 +0x1a

goroutine 3 gp=0xc000007180 m=nil [GC sweep wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc00007b780 sp=0xc00007b760 pc=0x104e158ce
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:408
runtime.bgsweep(0xc0000480e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:278 +0x94 fp=0xc00007b7c8 sp=0xc00007b780 pc=0x104e01934
runtime.gcenable.gowrap1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:203 +0x25 fp=0xc00007b7e0 sp=0xc00007b7c8 pc=0x104df6285
runtime.goexit({})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc00007b7e8 sp=0xc00007b7e0 pc=0x104e47c21
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:203 +0x66

goroutine 4 gp=0xc000007340 m=nil [GC scavenge wait]:
runtime.gopark(0xc0000480e0?, 0x1052b9190?, 0x1?, 0x0?, 0xc000007340?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc00007bf78 sp=0xc00007bf58 pc=0x104e158ce
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:408
runtime.(*scavengerState).park(0x105774f80)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:425 +0x49 fp=0xc00007bfa8 sp=0xc00007bf78 pc=0x104dff329
runtime.bgscavenge(0xc0000480e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:653 +0x3c fp=0xc00007bfc8 sp=0xc00007bfa8 pc=0x104dff8bc
runtime.gcenable.gowrap2()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:204 +0x25 fp=0xc00007bfe0 sp=0xc00007bfc8 pc=0x104df6225
runtime.goexit({})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc00007bfe8 sp=0xc00007bfe0 pc=0x104e47c21
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:204 +0xa5

goroutine 5 gp=0xc000007c00 m=nil [finalizer wait]:
runtime.gopark(0xc00007a648?, 0x104de9fa5?, 0xa8?, 0x1?, 0xc0000061c0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:402 +0xce fp=0xc00007a620 sp=0xc00007a600 pc=0x104e158ce
runtime.runfinq()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:194 +0x107 fp=0xc00007a7e0 sp=0xc00007a620 pc=0x104df52c7
runtime.goexit({})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695 +0x1 fp=0xc00007a7e8 sp=0xc00007a7e0 pc=0x104e47c21
created by runtime.createfing in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:164 +0x3d
zsh: abort      python3.12 main.py

Here is the go program
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "C"
    "github.com/livekit/protocol/auth"
    "github.com/livekit/protocol/livekit"
    lksdk "github.com/livekit/server-sdk-go/v2"
)



//export CreateRoom
func CreateRoom(roomName string) string{
        RoomClient := lksdk.NewRoomServiceClient("wss://first-room-042r2.livekit.cloud","my api key","my secret key")
        
        room,err := RoomClient.CreateRoom(context.Background(), &livekit.CreateRoomRequest{
            Name: roomName,
        }) // The problem is definitely from here

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("An error occurred in creating the room: %v\n", err.Error())
        }
    return room.String()
}

and here is my python code
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
import os


livekit = ctypes.util.find_library("livekit")
if not livekit:
    raise Exception("Library not found")

cwd = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(cwd,livekit)

livekit_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(path)
livekit_lib.CreateRoom.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
livekit_lib.CreateRoom.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]



def create_room(room_name:str):
    try:
        room = livekit_lib.CreateRoom(
            room_name.encode("utf-8"),
        )

        return room.decode("utf-8")
    except Exception as exc:
        raise Exception(exc)

create_room("Room #1")


You just need a larger computer. Look through the stacktrace and find where you send a array that is too long.
